# CSS body `background-image` aligned right on Chrome, Safari (webkit)

Tags: css, background-image, right-to-left, document-body

I've been struggling with a problem on webkit browsers (chrome & safari) while adapting a website for right-to-left readers (Arabic & Hebrew languages). Finally I reported this as a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95951), but I still need a workaround for this.

The problem

Assign a background image to the body tag, and position this background image to the right and repeat-y. Now, make the window smaller until the horizontal scrollbar appears. The background image will no longer be aligned to the right of the document, it will be positioned `x` pixels from the left where `x` is the width of the viewport.

Here's a simplified example, isolating the problem. The word "Contents" is expected to always be on top of the blue part of the background image.

```
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64, ...);
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
  }
  #contents {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contents">Contents</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also see the [screendump](https://bug-95951-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=162450) included in the WebKit bug report.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an absolutely positioned element?

```
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#bg {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvgAAAACAgMAAABQ2kAmAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlQTFRF5ev/9Pb/////KIKAcgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfcCQIMFSrrJQqoAAAAFUlEQVQY02PgWjU4wQoGokDUkHY+ACqhykF2Ey1yAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#contents {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="contents">Contents</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems to work for me as a workaround.

Comment: Yup! This seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Only problem beeing scroll related: Instead of width: 100% I'm using width: 760px (the width of the background image). For getting the background-image to scroll vertically I had to include some Javascript. In this simplified example it works great, on the full complex site my jQuery snippet will produce some flicker while moving the image down on scroll. Still the best solution so far, thanks Royce.